# Handle the Incoming Content from share button not working android 6.0 and higher

Tags: android, image, share

I have an app that receives data from the share option and until Android 6.0 it has been working fine. When the app is not running - and I use the share functionality (i.e. via an image). Pick my app. OnNewIntent get called and the intent cantains action.SEND and extras that is ok.
But, when the app is running in the background and I use the share option, then the onNewIntent get called and intent contains action.MAIN and no extras.

here is manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

java code:

```
@Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
 if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)&&intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM))
 {
     Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if ("text/".equals(type)) {
            String shareText = intent.getDataString();
           //handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            getDataFromUri(intent,activity);
        }
}
```

How do I fix this? Is there anything wrong with my code?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason why you use [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) ? This function exists only for afew rare edge cases (launchMode to "singleTop").

You should put your Intent-handling into `Activity-onCreate` and call [getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) to process send text/image service requests.